# I'm trying to install nativescript-google-maps-sdk in my nativescript angular 2 application

Tags: google-maps, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When I install the plugin it gets successfully installed but I get the following message in my terminal:

> nativescript-google-maps-sdk 3.0.0 for ios is not compatible with the
>   currently installed framework version 2.5.0.

This is my package.json

```
{
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "readme": "NativeScript Application",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "org.nativescript.virtualreality",
        "tns-ios": {
            "version": "2.5.0"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
        "email-validator": "^1.0.7",
        "nativescript-angular": "~1.5.1",
        "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^2.0.2",
        "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^3.11.4",
        "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.6.2",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "~5.2.0",
        "tns-core-modules": "2.5.2",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.3.5",
        "typescript": "~2.1.0"
    }
}
```

Since the tns 3.0 is still in RC phase I don't want to mess up my project. Isn't there any way of using the google-maps in the 2.5.* version of Nativescript

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade you nativescript modules to version ~3... "tns-core-modules": "2.5.2",

Comment: I did exactly that and it works now, thanks for the reply